# send xml to server

Tags: iphone

I am recording a video from iPhone and I want to show the video **live** on a diffrent server.

I am using a logic to take the snapshots of images that I am recording then convert imagedata **(20 images of recording at one time )** into string and send the string as xml to the server. 
I can parse the data on the server and save it as image.

How can I **send an  xml** of 20 images at one time to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the structure your XML?....

if you are sending them as String, you just need to work with nodes and childnodes.. something like:

```
<root>
 <images>
  <image>DATA</image>
  <image>DATA</image>
  <image>DATA</image>
 </images>
</root>
```

you can always send multiple files throug multipart request. The only thing you need is separate the content and their headers one by one, will be something like this:

```
---part separator
Content-Type: application/jpeg
Content-ID: test

... jpeg data goes here
---part separator
Content-Type: application/gif
Content-ID: test2

... gif data goes here
---part separator
```